# Unable to run or publish any workflows on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, ssl, workflow-manager, certificate

All my workflows in a SharePoint server stopped working.

I see this when trying to viewing workflows for an item:

> Some workflows may not be shown. We were unable to reach the workflow service.

Here is the error JSON returned from the server when I try to run a workflow manually from the browser:

```
[
{
"SchemaVersion":"15.0.0.0","LibraryVersion":"15.0.4763.1000","ErrorInfo":{
"ErrorMessage":"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL\u002fTLS secure channel.","ErrorValue":null,"TraceCorrelationId":"597cba9d-1b29-00d8-13d9-1856016bf83c","ErrorStackTrace":"   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)\r\n   at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManager.StartInternal(String workflowName, WorkflowStartParameters startParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.StartInstance(String serviceGroupName, String workflowName, String monitoringParam, String activationKey, IDictionary`2 payload)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.StartWorkflow(WorkflowSubscription subscription, IDictionary`2 payload)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.StartWorkflowOnListItem(WorkflowSubscription subscription, Int32 itemId, IDictionary`2 payload)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceServiceServerStub.StartWorkflowOnListItem_MethodProxy(WorkflowInstanceService target, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceServiceServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement xe)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement xe)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)\r\n   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()","ErrorCode":-1,"ErrorTypeName":"System.Net.WebException"
},"TraceCorrelationId":"597cba9d-1b29-00d8-13d9-1856016bf83c"
}
]
```

When trying to publish a workflow from SharePoint Designer 2013, I get this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
>   not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
>   System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
>   certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAs

I followed the steps here to export and reinstall the root certificate, but it didn't help (even after iisreset): http://blog.binarybits.net/programming/sharepoint/error-the-root-of-the-certificate-chain-is-not-a-trusted-root-authority-register-spworkflowservice-sharepoint-2013/

I don't remember making any changes to the server so I have absolutely no clue where to look for the problem. Ideas? Thank you.